# Error to assignment by two vector?

Tags: c++, assign

I have two problem,
the second file n_cartelle_mod.txt isn't completelly changed from n_cartelle.txt
and the second problem is assignment nomi_txt[cont] = n_cartelle[i]
why?
the problem is in the for where is the substr and when found a txt file and after there is the assignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string arg = argv[2];                       
    int arch;                                   
    string cambia ="cd ";
    string cartella = argv[1];                  

    vector <string> n_cartelle;
    vector <string> nomi_txt;
    int cont = 0;


    //start code 

    if(argc == 3) {

        cambia += cartella.substr();
        cambia += " && dir > n_cartelle.txt";

        const char * c_cambia = cambia.c_str(); 


        arch = system(c_cambia);
        if(arch == 0)
            cout << "\n Cartella cambiata con successo"<<endl
                 <<"\n  Documento di testo con nome e tipo di file creato con successo"<<endl;
        else{

            cout << "\nErrore nella chiamata a SYSTEM"<<endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //decifro il file creato:

        //prendo le stringhe dal file-----------------------------------------------


        ifstream in("n_cartelle.txt");
        ofstream out("n_cartelle_mod.txt");
        string linea;

        while(getline(in,linea)){

            if(linea.size() < 2)
                out << "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\n";
            else
                out << linea<<"\n";

            //n_cartelle.push_back(linea);
        }
        cout << "File creato e modificato, vado avanti\n";

        string linea2;
        ifstream in2("n_cartelle_mod.txt");
        while(getline(in2,linea2))
            n_cartelle.push_back(linea2);

        cout << "Caricato il <vector>\n";

        //-------------------------END-------------------------------------------


        //problem is here

        for(int i=0; i < n_cartelle.size()-4; ++i){

            cout <<"i volte: "<<i<<endl;

            if(n_cartelle[i].substr(n_cartelle[i].size()-3) == "txt"){
                cout << "capperi\n";

                nomi_txt[cont] = n_cartelle[i];


                cont++;
            }


        }



    }


    else {
        cout << "Parametri inesatti.\n\n"       
             << "Esempio di utilizzo:\n        Search.exe c:\\\\User paolo"<<endl;

    }
```

Comment: Another problem is that some of the code is missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nomi_txt[cont] = n_cartelle[i];
```

Since you never set the size of `nomi_txt`, this will result in undefined behavior as you will be accessing elements out of the bounds of the vector.  If you want `nomi_txt` to have the same number of elements as `n_cartelle`, you need to resize it:

```
nomi_txt.resize(n_cartelle.size());
```

prior to the loop.

[Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22152656/529761) already mentioned the issue with closing the `std::ofstream` prior to reopening the file for input.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close `out` before you do `ifstream in2("n_cartelle_mod.txt");`. Output to files is buffered by default, and the last block of output won't be flushed to the file until you do this.

Or you could use `endl` instead of `"\n"` in your `out <<` lines; this outputs a newline and also flushes the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that appears is that the last 2 vector items in `n_cartelle` are skipped by the `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < n_cartelle.size()-4; ++i) {
```

Further, I believe the `nomi_text` should use a `.push_back` or similar function to add elements to it rather than an indexed assignment to indices that might not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have to substitute this statement

```
nomi_txt[cont] = n_cartelle[i];
```

for

```
nomi_txt.push_back( n_cartelle[i] );
```

because vector nomi_txt is empty and you may not use the subscript operator to access elements that do not exist.